# Wordpress add html to Site Title

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to bold one of the words in the site title of a **wordpress** blog. I read that this is not possible so I went the `jquery` route to replace the text but it is not working either.

I have tried placing the code below in the `header.php` and `footer.php` but I can't get it to run .

```
<!-- Change site title -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("h1#site-title a").text("name<b>surname</b>");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to try to directly insert that into the `header.php` file instead of using the proper `wp_enqueue_script()` method, then three things need to take place.

1) - You need to make sure this is called `after wp_head()`

2) - If you're trying to insert `html` into the document, then you need to use `.html()`

3) - There may be some conflict, so you should use the `no conflict ready handler`

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("h1#site-title a").html("name<b>surname</b>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly it. I think there must have been a conflict. Cheers